# GL_MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT returns 0

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm currently testing my library on other machines.  Unfortunately, anisotropic filtering is causing problems.

On my machine (NVIDIA GeForce 580M GTX) it works fine and as expected.

On the test machine however, it's failing because when querying GL_MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, I get 0.  I was unaware this was possible from reading [the spec.](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_filter_anisotropic.txt).  It's also a (fairly) new laptop with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250 which [should support](http://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/device/Mobility%20Radeon%20HD%204250%20Graphics) that extension.

Any ideas why GL_MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT would return 0?  Thanks,

Comment: Does this need to be enabled with the Catalyst control center, or some other configuration app?

Comment: It's a laptop, so make sure you've updated your drivers. What OpenGL version number do you get? Also, are you sure you're getting 0 at all? Maybe you're getting a GL error and 0 is what the value had originally.